# 16bit floating point

Tags: floating-point, 16-bit

I am having trouble understanding 16-bit floating points for an upcoming exam. 
I'm having the following digits in binary(after conversion);

+11100.111000<sub>2</sub> = 28.875<sub>2</sub>. I got 28 easily, but how do I get '875' ?

Thanks

Comment: "get" in what way? algorithmically convert to a decimal string?

Comment: You mean 28.875 base 10, not base 2, right?

Comment: That doesn't look like floating point so much as an assumed decimal (binary?) point.  If it were floating point, you wouldn't normally have a decimal point in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

In a number, the value of a digit is multiplied by a constant, depending on the position. Let's take an example for a decimal number:

> ab.cd<sub>10</sub> = a*10<sup>1</sup> + b*10<sup>0</sup> + c*10<sup>-1</sup> + d*10<sup>-2</sup>

It works similarly for binary numbers. For the portion to the right of the binary point in your example:

> 0.111000<sub>2</sub> = 2<sup>-1</sup> + 2<sup>-2</sup> + 2<sup>-3</sup> = 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.125 = 0.875.

Comment: Okay, that is right, however, where do I get those numbers from ?

Comment: They are just 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 - just the reciprocal of the normal binary numbers

Comment: @ChrisArom Which numbers? The binary portion of my answer came from you. If you mean the 2^-1 (and so on), that is because it is a base-2 (i.e., binary) number. For base-10 (decimal) it would be 10^-1. For base-8 (octal) it would be 8^-1.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it now :) Time for more practice.

Answer (score 1):

Left side of the . is multiply by 2, right side is divide by 2.

So you got 0.1110

0.1 = 0.5
0.01 = 0.25
0.001 = 0.125
----------------+
0.875